# Comparing String Date To A Datetime 

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, date

I have a stored proc that takes a date a string parameter. The data coming in looks like the form `yyyy-MM-dd` in the database the dates are save in the form `2012-02-26 06:00:00.000` (a time is attached to them. When I run the sql it always returns nothing because it cant find a comparison:

```
'select t_typday from ' + @dbName+ '.dbo.Calendar ' +
' where T_date LIKE ''' + @dateFilter + '%''';
```

Comment: You store datetime values as _strings_???

Comment: The more important question is: why do you pass strings for a datetime field at all? Use parameters with type `datetime`  instead(i'm afraid that you're also open for SQL-Injection).

Comment: will that fix my issue of comparing?

Comment: I need the sql to be a string like this. How do I add a datetime parameter to this sql if the sql has to a string?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - The OP appears to be doing some dynamic SQL. Using an unambiguous date format would sort the issue, as the "passed in" date will need to be part of the SQL string.

Comment: @NickLaMarca: Therefor you need to show more. We need to know the actual schema of the table and see some sample filters(f.e. does the user can choose a start-date and an end-date?).

Comment: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/04/26/Unambiguous-dates-in-SQL-Server.aspx

Comment: I am using dynamic sql. The table field "t_date" is a datetime field

Comment: [I can has string to store date valyooz?](http://www.globalnerdy.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/icanhasstring.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the date in your table to the `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm` date format before comparing it with your string parameter in that format using `LIKE`:

To fix your existing code with minimal changes, change `T_date` to `CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),T_date,121)`, producing:

```
'select t_typday from ' + @dbName+ '.dbo.Calendar ' + 
' where CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),T_date,121) LIKE ''' + @dateFilter + '%''';
```

If you do not perform the conversion, you are comparing a **local format string** (based on the `@@LANGUAGE` setting), such as `Apr 12 2012 12:00AM` with your string in `@dateFilter` which contains, for example, `2012-04-12`. This is why the comparison is not working.

Of course passing in a parameter of type `DATE` into your stored procedure would be a much better solution, as several comments have already mentioned. That would allow you to compare the date in `T_date` with the passed in `DATE` value in `@dateFilter` using a simple expression such as:

```
CONVERT(DATE,T_date)=@dateFilter
```

Comment: How do I change this dynamic sql to have @dateFilter be a datetime?

Comment: You can convert within the stored procedure via `CONVERT(DATETIME,@dateFilter)` or just change the type of the argument in the stored procedure itself to be of type `DATETIME` instead of `VARCHAR(50)` or whatever it currently is. If you just want the date as the filter, make the parameter to the stored proc of type `DATE` and then you can compare using something simple like: `CONVERT(DATE,T_date)=@dateFilter`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an unambiguous date format - something that can't be interpreted as several possible dates.

See [this](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/04/26/Unambiguous-dates-in-SQL-Server.aspx) and [this](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2009/12/08/unambiguous-date-formats-t-sql-tuesday-001.aspx) for options.